# Who are all the characters to have touched The One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

Who are all the characters in *The Lord of the Rings* to have touched The One Ring, actually worn it on their fingers, or otherwise had it in their possession (even for a brief period of time)? Please indicate the type of contact, duration, order, and any other pertinent information.

Comment: Isn't this a classical 'list' question and thus not suitable for SE?

Comment: @APaleShadow it is a list, but I think its borderline acceptable because the list is concrete, known and finite, and will never change, so it *is* possible to accept a single correct answer that will remain correct indefinitely.

Comment: I've realised that there's a distinction between open ended list questions and closed list questions. See http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic for discussion

Comment: Duplicate? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/how-many-wearers-of-the-one-ring-were-there

Comment: See also this awesome graphic from lotrproject: http://lotrproject.com/blog/2013/01/20/visual-timeline-of-the-one-ring/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12742/how-many-wearers-of-the-one-ring-were-there) addresses who *wore* the ring, but to answer the [pre-edit] question:

From the LOTR [Wikia](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/One_Ring), including momentary 'bearers':
[image]

Comment: Any idea which of these involve skin contact? Which of these characters actually _wore_ the ring? I have add this additional request to my question as well. Thank you!

Comment: @coleopterist At least in the movie, Boromir momentarily held the ring without skin contact.  So I think that is what the list is.

Comment: Pretty sure Gandalf never wore the ring

Comment: @mort - the question isn't restricted to those who wore it.  By the way, *somebody* probably also touched it in Rivendell - see Many Meetings: "*when he had dressed, Frodo found that while he slept the Ring had been hung about his neck on a new chain, light but strong*".

Comment: @mh01 assuming Elrond knew what it was at the time, and was overly (sufficiently?) paranoid about it, it's possible he threaded the chain onto the ring in Frodo's pocket without touching the ring itself.

Comment: @mort I'm pretty sure the Gandalf entry is from when he was showing Frodo the hidden writing on the Ring back at Bag End.  You're right that he didn't wear it, but he did touch/hold it for some short period there.

Comment: @Izkata the movies are a corruption of the lore, Boromir never touched the ring. He desired to, which is why Frodo fled the company.

Comment: @Solemnity Excuse me, how come Frodo held it for 17 years? Did he spent 17 years to figure out if the ring Bilbo was holding is The One Ring? After the birthday party of Bilbo 111 birthday?

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 Yes and no.  It took 17 years to figure out what the Ring was about, but it was Gandalf that did the figuring.  He asked Frodo to hide it until he knew what to do with it.  I'll attempt to ask if Gandalf was ignorant of the effects the ring would have.

Comment: @lamwaiman1988 And- it was also Frodo's birthday.  They [share the same birthday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frodo_Baggins#Background).

Comment: @Solemnity Do you mean that after the birthday party, it took Gandalf 17 years before he came back?

Comment: Also Gil-Galad probably touched, though didn't wear the ring. Sauron wrestled him in single combat and Isildur specifically says his hand, with the ring, touched Gil Galad. "The Ring misseth, maybe, the heat of Sauron’s hand, which was black and yet burned like fire, and so Gil-galad was destroyed"

Comment: @Keen - IIRC, Gandalf held the Ring with tongs, not his hands.

Comment: Gandalf definitely touched it, but didn't wear it. Sam definitely wore it. Also, this list is (possibly) missing one. When Frodo was in Rivendell recovering from his wound at Weathertop, someone took it from his pocket (or maybe his hand) and put it on a chain around his neck. Possibly that was Elrond, Gandalf, or some nameless elf, but that person probably touched it. Also, since you're duplicating, you're missing Frodo before and after Tom Bombadil.

Answer (score 6):

**Sauron wore it**... though in the movie it is worn over a glove... but that means nothing in the grand scheme of things.

**Isildur wore it.** This was why he could not bring himself to destroy it.

There was never a real list of what might have happened to it After Isildur wore it as the thing was 'lost' and found in the river.

**Déagol touched it**, since he was a poor river thing I would admit that it was skin contact on the hand and probably why he would not give it up to Sméagol and Sméagol had to kill him for it.

**Sméagol wore it** and it turned him into Gollum.

**Bilbo wore it** as that was how he escaped Gollum, and subsequently uses it after that.

**Frodo wore it**, as that was how the story and movie was based.

> and he was wearing it when Gollum bit it off his finger.

**Gandalf touched it**, more than likely skin contact as to why you see him toss the ring down and recoil from it, to place the ring in something protective to give to Bilbo.

**Bombadil wore it**, and the ring disappeared rather than Tom disappearing.

**Samwise touched it** and wore it as a necklace for sometime until Frodo was back.  I believe he never wore it on his finger, though I would like to conclude he might have made a better ringbearer.

**Gollum touched it again**

> and  died with it when the ring was destroyed.

Comment: Worthwhile for me to recreate table and edit my answer with short-form versions of this in a sixth column?

Comment: In the books, Sam *did* wear the Ring. After the attack of Shelob, when he thought Frodo dead, Sam took the Ring.  When the orcs approached, Sam slipped on the Ring and followed them.

Comment: I was never 100% sure that Gandalf did handle the Ring in Bag End or not. Will have to check the book to find the appropriate passage.

Comment: The Ring didn't disappear while Bombadil was wearing it, he made it disappear later.

Comment: "This was why he could not bring himself to destroy it" - is not confirmed. Better evidence is that he wore it to try to escape the orc attack that killed him.